# .NET 7 MemoryCache GetProperty returns null

Tags: .net

I have a code that works fine with .NET 6, but ever since I upgraded to .NET 7 code is not working.

Here's the code;

```
            // Get the empty definition for the EntriesCollection
        var cacheEntriesCollectionDefinition = typeof(MemoryCache).GetProperty("EntriesCollection", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

        if (cacheEntriesCollectionDefinition!=null)
        {
        
            // Populate the definition with your IMemoryCache instance.  
            // It needs to be cast as a dynamic, otherwise you can't
            // loop through it due to it being a collection of objects.
            var cacheEntriesCollection = cacheEntriesCollectionDefinition.GetValue(_cache) as dynamic;

            if (cacheEntriesCollection!=null)
            {
                // Define a new list we'll be adding the cache entries too
                List<ICacheEntry> cacheCollectionValues = new List<ICacheEntry>();

                foreach (var cacheItem in cacheEntriesCollection)
                {
                    // Get the "Value" from the key/value pair which contains the cache entry   
                    ICacheEntry cacheItemValue = cacheItem.GetType().GetProperty("Value").GetValue(cacheItem, null);

                    // Add the cache entry to the list
                    cacheCollectionValues.Add(cacheItemValue);
                }

                
                var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                var keysToRemove = cacheCollectionValues.Where(d => regex.IsMatch(d.Key.ToString())).Select(d => d.Key).ToList();

                foreach (var key in keysToRemove)
                {
                    _cache.Remove(key);
                }
            }
        }
```

**typeof(MemoryCache).GetProperty("EntriesCollection")** always returns null. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why are you using reflection?!

Comment: `is not working` isn't an error description. What in all this is returning null? What are the actual contents of the cache? Post a *reproducible* sample, ie code that actually fills the cache with the entries that should be returned

Comment: Why are you trying to use *private* members? Private members are by definition not part of a type's API and can change at any time, for any reason, even among minor releases

Comment: `How can I fix this?` don't try to call private members to begin with. If you can't use the MemoryCache type the way you want, post a question so people can help you. There may be a way to do what you want, or you may be trying to do the wrong thing.

Comment: Why is `var regex = new Regex(pattern)` used to search *inside* cache elements for example? A memory cache is **not a database**. If you want an in-memory database you can use other types, even SQLite in in-memory mode. Even the attempt to scan all lines in all entries in the "cache" will be far, far slower than searching an indexed column in SQLite in in-memory mode

Comment: I explained the code. I use this method because after .Net Core, MemoryCache.Default is not available.

Answer (score 3):

The internal design of [`MemoryCache` has changed](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/48567). See the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/src/MemoryCache.cs) at GitHub.

If you have a binding on a *non-public* member, then you have to count with the option the implementation changes at any time, even when a minor update of .NET is done.

When such bindings are a *must* for you, it is a good idea to develop a separate unit test to verify such code is working.

Comment: Even better, don't even try to use private members

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sure; however, the OP might have a valid case for that. If yes, use caution, use unit tests, manage your environment lifecycle, don't be surprised things break :)

Comment: That's seldom the case, especially when the code starts getting that ugly. In this case code is using regular expressions to search *lines* inside each cache entry and then remove the matches. That's the job of a dictionary or even SQLite, not a memory cache

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to reply to this after a long time, but I just encountered a version error similar to this. This code will fix the error

```
var fieldInfo = typeof(MemoryCache).GetField("_coherentState", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var propertyInfo = fieldInfo.FieldType.GetProperty("EntriesCollection", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
var value = fieldInfo.GetValue(_memoryCache);
var dict = propertyInfo.GetValue(value) as dynamic;


List<ICacheEntry> cacheCollectionValues = new List<ICacheEntry>();

foreach (var cacheItem in dict)
{
    ICacheEntry cacheItemValue = cacheItem.GetType().GetProperty("Value").GetValue(cacheItem, null);
    cacheCollectionValues.Add(cacheItemValue);
}

var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var keysToRemove = cacheCollectionValues.Where(d => regex.IsMatch(d.Key.ToString())).Select(d => d.Key).ToList();

foreach (var key in keysToRemove)
{
    _memoryCache.Remove(key);
}
```